# How to convert your Exiting MVC application into a SAAS model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, asp.net-mvc-4, simplemembership

We have an application hosted in Azure and it works just fine. This application is based on MVC4 along with `SimpleMembership` and **Entity Framework** with **Code first**. When the application is hosted in the web it just works. Code first creates DB, Roles and the Admin user.

Now we have a requirement of providing the same application to different Companies on a SAAS based Model. For that we had two approaches.

- We can store the information of all the companies on the same database.
- We can store the information each company in their own and separate database.

We want to go with the second approach so that each company will have their own Database. Each time a company register a separate database for them (But there will be only one web application) will be initializes and their Roles and Admin user will be created. So that when a person of that particular user logs in they will operate with their own database.

But the problem arises when any method or properties from the WebSecurity class is called from the SimpleMembership provider. Lets say an user from company "**ABC**" is logged in we can initialize the `WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection()` to use the DataBase associated with te ABC Database. Whe some one else logs in from another Company lets say "**XYZ**" company we need to tell the WebSecurity to use the database associated with **XYZ** Database. Now as  `WebSecurity` is initialized with the **ABC** Database it does not work with **XYZ** databse and twrowing an error saying `WebSecurity` can only be initialized once.

Now can you please help me figuring out a way so that my `WebSecurity` can work with dynamic Context then that will be great. Or you can let me know a solution to work with multiple databases. Please note that we do not want to restructure our app and re write it from the beginning.

Comment: Is it possible to use ASP.NET MVC 5 instead of ASP.NET MVC 4? MVC 5 has an updated ASP.NET Identity system that's a lot more configurable than SimpleMembership.

Comment: Hey @JonGalloway Thanks a lot for your Reply. We have decided to Migrate from SimpleMembership to Identity. But the problem is that there are not enough Documentations available for it.